# Distinct over a list of lists of objects

Tags: c#

Consider a List of List of objects of the same entity

```
List<List<Car>> = {{ new Car("Opel"), new Car("VW") },
                   { new Car("Opel"), new Car("Fiat"), new Car("Ford")}}
```

I would like to have only distinct car models across all objects in all lists but I would like to keep the lists where they are.(no merge everything in one list)

Result:

```
    List<List<Car>> = {{ new Car("Opel"), new Car("VW") },
                      { new Car("Fiat"), new Car("Ford")}}
```

I created a custom equality comparer so far and I use distinct() from Linq.

What is anyway the fastest way to achieve this ?

Comment: So, you mean that "Opel" can occur in several lists, but only once in each list?  Perhaps you would be better served by a `List<HashSet<Car>>` instead of a list of lists.

Comment: Tim asks a fair question -- are you really stuck with the data structure you initially presented? Can you do anything about the form of the data before you have to get the distinct entries?

Comment: yes Only once. if opel is in List[1] it cannot appear in any other List

Comment: Tim I cannot alter the form of the data

Comment: So a car model shall be kept in the *first* list it occurs in and be removed from all *subsequent* lists? Or does it not matter in which of the list the car model "survives"?

Comment: You say, you already have a solution and you worry about  the performance? So what is your solution and where is the bottleneck?

Comment: If you're using LINQ you're not "keeping lists where they are"

Answer (score 0):

"Fastest" way? For whom? The code to find it or the developer to write it? :)

Modify whatever logic maintains these lists to also put the car in a HashSet first. If Add returns false for the hashset then the car is already known; don't add it to any list

```
void Add(Car x){
  if(_carsHashSet.Add(x))
    return;

  //rest of your logic here to add car to some list
}
```

Provide overrides of GetHashCode and Equals on Car that return the name.GetHashCode and `other.Equals(name)` so that hashset can work correctly on the car name

```
class Car{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  override GetHashCode(){
    return Name.GetHashCode();
  }

  override Equals(object other){
    return other is Car c && c.Name != null && c.Name.Equals(Name);
  }
}
```

If your question is not about the process that adds to the lists, but instead you're trying to dedupe the lists, take the same approach of using a hashset as you loop over all the cars in the list of lists; adding every car you see to the hashset. If the add operation returns false, the car is already known, remove it from the list

You can iterate the outer List forwards with a foreach, but I recommend iterating the inner list backwards with a `for` as it makes the code simpler not having to worry about the index of subsequent items altering when you remove one

```
foreach(var ls in cars)
  for(int x = ls.Count-1; x>=0; x--)
    if(hashSet.Add(ls[x]))
      ls.RemoveAt(x);
```

Comment: I'd love for someone to enlighten me as to how this answer is "not useful"